# laravel livewire how to make sum of two deferent input valve fetched form database table and get result in another input

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

Hello im new to laravel livewire now im trying to sum of two values and result get in another input filed.
but laravel i did this using jQuery now im trying livewire instead of jQuery.

now im getting 1st input value from database table by foreach loop 2nd input value im giving manually inserting, 3rd input im getting result.

**problem 1**

> but im facing problem in 1st input if i use foreach with
> `wire:model="Amount"` & `value="{{ $prices->Amount}}"` at same time in
> input i get empty.

```
@foreach ($price $prices)
<label>Amount</label>
<input wire:model="Amount" name="Amount" value="{{ $prices->Amount}}">
@endforeach

<label>Disscount</label>
<input type="text" wire:model="Disscount" name="Disscount" >

<label>Result</label>
<input type="text" value="{{ $result }}" name="Disscount" >
```

**problem 2**

> if i removed code `value="{{ $prices->Amount}}"` & keeping `wire:model="Amount"` i dont get value from foreach because i removed `value="{{ $prices->Amount}}"` this time i entered manually insert value in input it works i get result, but i need to sum value with foreach value.
> if i removed `wire:model="Amount"` & keeping `value="{{ $prices->Amount}}"` sum not works because value not reach to controller without `wire:mode`.

```
@foreach ($price $prices)
<label>Amount</label>
<input wire:model="Amount" name="Amount" value="{{ $prices->Amount}}">
@endforeach

<label>Disscount</label>
<input type="text" wire:model="Disscount" name="Disscount" >

<label>Result</label>
<input type="text" value="{{ $result }}" name="Disscount" >
```

my controller

```
public $result;
public $Amount;
public $Disscount;

public function updated() //used for sum
{
    $this->result = $this->Amount - $this->Disscount;
}

  public function mount()
{
    $this->price = Pricing::all();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `wire:model` on one Amount variable but doing that inside of `foreach` of prices.

So it's not entirely clear what exactly you want to mount.

You shouldn't use `value="..."` as Livewire automatically gets the value from public property via `wire:model`.

Also you should probably use `wire:model` on the Result input.

Comment: im new to livewire can you answer writing code i can understand easily

Comment: Sorry I can't easily write code as I'm on mobile. Maybe tomorrow when I'm back into the office, if no one answers it before me.

Comment: Hello sir im waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($allPrices as $price)
<label>Amount {{ $loop->iteration }}</label>
<input value="{{ $price }}" disabled>
@endforeach

<label>Disscount</label>
<input type="number" wire:model="disscount" name="Disscount" min="0" >

<label>Result</label>
<input type="number" wire:model="result" name="Result" disabled>
```

//component

```
public $result = 0;
public $disscount;
public $totalPrice;
public $allPrices;

public function mount()
{
    $this->allPrices = Price::pluck('amount', 'id');
    $this->totalPrice = Price::sum('amount');
}

public function updatedDisscount()
{
    if ($this->disscount > 0)
      $this->result = $this->totalPrice - $this->disscount;
}
```

UPDATE: You can just do like this, no need to check/take data from input, just calculate inside the components (from DB) and whenever the disscount data is changed, then it'll calculate using `updatedDisscount()`

Comment: I'm feaching amount value from database.by below  code. foreach ($price $prices)
<label>Amount</label>
<input wire:model="Amount" name="Amount" value="{{ $prices->Amount}}">
endforeach

Comment: help me with loop

Comment: Is price amount editable? or they'll assign whatever `$price->Amount` they'll receive?

Comment: non editable its feach from database